# Transforming a list with differing number of elements to a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame by combining a data frame with a list. The problem is that each element of the list is not the same length. I read this link: http://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-list-to-a-data-frame/ and example four is exactly what I need, but I want to automate the process of naming the rows. I have over 100 rows I need to name and I don't want to name them all explicitly.

```
example <- list("a", c("b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"))
```

should look like this:

```
row1 | a <NA> <NA>
row2 | b  c   <NA>
row3 | d  e    f
```

Comment: Could you please share some example data (a smaller version of the 100+ rows that you have) and describe the desired output for that data?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). So, the least you can do is including example four as that link may become dead in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stri_list2matrix` to convert the `list` to `matrix`.  It will fill `NA` for the `list` elements that have `length` less than the `max` length found in the `list`.

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(example, byrow=TRUE)
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  NA   NA  
#[2,] "b"  "c"  NA  
#[3,] "d"  "e"  "f"
```

---

Or another option is from `base R`, where we assign the `length` to the maximum length, thereby filling NA for the `list` elements with less length.  We use `sapply` so that when the `list` elements are of equal length, it `simplify` to `matrix`.

```
t(sapply(example, `length<-`, max(lengths(example))))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  NA   NA  
#[2,] "b"  "c"  NA  
#[3,] "d"  "e"  "f"
```

NOTE: No packages are used here ...  If you need a `data.frame`, wrap the output with `as.data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert each list component to a `"ts"` class object, `cbind` them to an `"mts"` class object (this will pad with NAs), and transpose giving a character matrix, `mat`.  Set the row names.  Finally convert that to a data frame. No packages are used.

```
mat <- t(do.call(cbind, Map(ts, example)))
rownames(mat) <- paste0("row", seq_along(example)) ##
DF <- as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ###
```

giving:

```
> DF
     V1   V2   V3
row1  a <NA> <NA>
row2  b    c <NA>
row3  d    e    f
```

**Note:** The question asked for a data frame and for row names; however, if row names are not needed omit the line marked ## and if a character matrix is sufficient then omit the line marked ###.

**Update**  Fixed spelling of stringsAsFactors.  Also minor simplification, add Note.